# count elements with specific data using ES6 concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to use `ecmascript 6` variable concatenation.

Expecting `exists` in console but getting error.  Please help:

```js
let path = 'abc';
if($('.title[data-path=${path}]').length > 0){
  console.log('exists');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title' data-path = 'abc'>lorem</div>
<div class='title' data-path = 'def'>ipsum</div>
<div class='title' data-path = 'abc'>lorem</div>
```

Comment: use template literals not `''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use concatenation instead

```js
let path = 'abc';
if($(`.title[data-path=${path}]`).length > 0){
  console.log('exists');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title' data-path = 'abc'>lorem</div>
<div class='title' data-path = 'def'>ipsum</div>
<div class='title' data-path = 'abc'>lorem</div>
```

Comment: check the edits now